# CSS rules newbie

Tags: css

Is there a way to simplify the following css rule so that .x-grid-row selector won't have to be repeated?

```css
#OpenRequestListGrid .x-grid-row, #MyRequestListGrid .x-grid-row {
    line-height: 13px;
    padding: 0 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #BBB;
}
```

Important issue here is that I don't want to specify .x-grid-row by itself as this rule is from a larger library.

**Note**: maybe I wasn't clear the first time but I don't want to use .x-grid-row as this will effect other grids that I want to leave alone. I would like to target just my two grids. What I am aiming for is not repeating the same config twice one for each grid ID.

**HTML sample** :

```
<div id="dontChangeMe" class="x-grid-row">
<div id="OpenRequestListGrid" class="x-grid-row">
<div id="MyRequestListGrid" class="x-grid-row">
```

Comment: if you don't have any other .x-grid-row, you can just do .x-grid-row { style...}, otherwise you can add a class for both #Open.. and #My.. and just do .newClass .x-grid-row { style... }

Comment: Without more information (the markup, maybe), I don't know how I could tell.

Comment: You might look into http://lesscss.org/. Because adding code to remove code makes a lot of sense.

Comment: What do you mean **specifically** by *not repeating the same config twice*?

Comment: Here is another example that illustrates the repetition      .                                    #OpenRequestListGrid .x-grid-row-alt .x-grid-cell .x-grid-row-alt .x-grid-rowwrap-div,
#MyRequestListGrid .x-grid-row-alt .x-grid-cell .x-grid-row-alt .x-grid-rowwrap-div {
    background-color: #B0B0B0;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Answer is there really isn't another way. Repeating element id and then the same selector is necessary. Thanks to all those who replied.

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't have variables, but when you want to select **all** elements `.x-grid-row` in your document, you should simplify it to:

```
.x-grid-row {
    line-height: 13px;
    padding: 0 1px;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #BBB;
}
```

Or just search for a common parent of your `.x-grid-row` when talking about a partial scope and use it like:

```
#common-parent .x-grid-row {
    ...
}
```

or

```
.common-parent .x-grid-row {
    ...
}
```

or any other css selectors ;)

**EDIT**

I just reread your question and you could also use a global selector like `.x-grid-row {...}` when you want to address *a lot of* elements and just specify more selectors like `#inner-box .x-grid-row { ... }` to change values back to default *for only few* elements.

Comment: So that's exactly what I am doing, the question here is ifI can do something like this instead:                            #OpenRequestListGrid, #MyRequestListGrid .x-grid-row

Comment: Can you provide some HTML example?

Comment: added to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using .x-grid-row or using a selector which is a parent to both #OpenRequestListGrid and #OpenRequestListGrid.

Comment: there are other grids I don't want to effect that already have this selector.